# How to dynamically put a layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have designed a layout in XML and want to generate it multiple time via a loop inside the main XML layout. How to do that.
My main XML layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
>    <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/question_listView">
    </ListView>    </ScrollView>
```

And layout i want to use dynamically is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/question_layout_xml">
<!-- Question Title  -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="This Is The Title Of Question Of January"
    android:id="@+id/question_title"
     />
<!--  Question Description -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="This Is The Description Of The Question You See Above And Below Is The Rating Bar"
    android:id="@+id/question_desc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question_title"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to generate the above layout for a given number of times and put a new value to `TextViews` every-time. I tried calling `TextViews` with id but i also have to change the id of `TextViews` every-time.

Comment: Do you want to add a row to the ListView? If so, use an adapter. You can find a lot of easy examples online (extends BaseAdapter for instance). Also, don't put a ListView inside a ScrollView because the ListView is scrollable. Put it in a LinearLayout or other.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to show data in list view.

Read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

In general, your adapter which is used in list view will create layouts (and assign data to it) based on  how many data is in adapter dynamically.

EDIT: you might be in first step interested in ArrayAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: especially the `getView()` method. this is where you decide which `xml-layout` to use